# Spring Session Replication Problem

Tags: apache, spring, tomcat, session-replication

I've currently researching in load balancing my Spring project. I've used Apache web server as front-end to multiple Tomcat instances. I've used mod_jk for the load balancing. When I run it, if I shutdown one server, i had to login again to the system. Previously I also tried it in simpler example with the Tomcat's session example program and the session replication worked fine.

This is my configuration for the Apache's `httpd.conf` mod_jk part:

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile logs/jk.log
JkLogLevel debug
JkLogLevel info
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"

JkMount /test balancer <-- this is the spring program
JkMount /test/* balancer <-- this is the spring program
JkMount /jk_status status`
```

And this is my workers.properties setting:

```
workers.tomcat_home=/worker1
workers.java_home=$JAVA_HOME
ps=/

worker.list=balancer,status

worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.lbfactor=1

worker.worker2.port=8109
worker.worker2.host=localhost
worker.worker2.type=ajp13
worker.worker2.lbfactor=1

worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.balance_workers=worker1,worker2
worker.balancer.method=B
worker.balancer.sticky_session=1

worker.status.type=status
```

And I've put a sample of one of my tomcat's server.xml here: http://pastebin.com/0j0ta2WA

I've also added `<distributable/>` tag to my application's `web.xml`. Is there something I missed here that made the session replication not working?

- Tomcat 5.5
- Apache 2.2
- mod_jk
- Spring 2.5.6
- JDK 1.6.0_01

Comment: JDK 1.6.0_01 ouch... the latest is JDK 1.6.0_24

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a jvmRoute defined in your server.xml?
Here are the docs:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/engine.html
I would have looked at your server.xml but the link is wrong.

Comment: sorry for the incorrect link, I've updated it. And for the jvmRoute, I've defined it in both configuration file. I also read that Spring's dependency injection problem is the cause for non-replicating session problem, is it correct?

Comment: How is your login session being handled?  Are you using something apache, tomcat, or spring specific?  Or did you roll your own and add a something to the httpsession by hand?